# How do I flush memory use in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing problem of site break down. Since this is the site related to photos. It’s using almost 95% of memory of server. When it reaches to 100% the site is down.
I checked from the profiler, and get following details:

```
Loading Time: Base Classes   0.0404
Controller Execution Time ( Events / Get Series Images )  10.7655
Total Execution Time   10.8061

MEMORY USAGE : 3,948,864 bytes
```

For detail please see the attached file.

Here data are fetched from **Progress server using JSON**. I am surprise what made it so.
But in my mind one thing hunt, why not to free the memory when work is done?
I went to different forum of CI but could not get the answer.

I tried to use **ob_end_flush(), ob_flush()**,.. but could not get desire result.
I am too is unaware about how to use in CI.

I hope I am able to clear my problem.
Thank you in advance for the support.

I am using HMVC.

CODE

```
// controller
    public function get_event_images(){    
        // pagination
        $data['current_page'] = @$_GET['page']?@$_GET['page']:1;

        $data['event_id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);   
        $data['event_name'] = urldecode($this->uri->segment(4));  
        $url = JSON_URL."jsread.p?call=treeimg&user=&lang=en&tree=".$data['series_id']."&sort=last&max=".MAX_RECORD."&startpage=".$data['current_page']."&pagesize=".PAGE_SIZE;         
        $json_formated_data =  readJSONURL($url);  

        //extract array of images only
        $data['images'] = getData($json_formated_data);

        $image_stat = getImageStat($json_formated_data);
        $data['total_images']= $image_stat[6];  
        $data['total_rows'] = $image_stat[5];

        $data['main_content'] = 'eventimages';  
        $data['title'] = "Event Images";

        // store series details in session
        $newdata = array(
            'event_id'  =>$data['event_id'],
            'event_name'=> $data['event_name']
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

        $this->load->view('ktmevent/template_page', $data);         
    }



// view
    if(!empty($images)):
        foreach($images as $data):
            echo  "<li>";   
                echo  "<div class=\"image\">";  
                echo "<a href=\"".site_url('events/image_detail/'.$series_id."/".$data['Photono'])."\">";
                echo "<img src=\"http://www.mysite.com".$data['Thumburl']."\" />";
                echo "</a>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div>";
                echo anchor('events/image_detail/'.$series_id.'/'.$data['Photono'], 'Detail');
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</li>";
        endforeach;
    endif;
```

Comment: Please show some code, it's pretty much impossible to help without seeing where the memory is being used in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with finding out what the memory usage is during each action. Just output the memory using the PHP function memory_get_usage():

http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php

Then you should be able to determine the actions that would cause your application to fill up the memory buffers.

Comment: Can I have one simple example regarding it?

Comment: The link shows an example, copied and pasted here for your view:

    <?php echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; /* ex. 36640 */ $a = str_repeat("Hello", 4242); echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; /* ex. 57960 */ unset($a); echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; /* ex. 36744
 */ ?>